# NHibernate mapping trouble

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, one-to-many

I have the following object model:

- A top-level abstract class `Element` with many children and descendants.
- A class `Event`.
- Each `Element` contains a bag of `Event`s.
- Each `Event` has a pointer to the parent `Element`.

Up till now - pretty standart one-to-many relationship.

But, I want to use table per concrete class strategy. So, the class `Element` is not mapped to the database. I've tried to solve it this way: each of the concrete descendants of `Element` defines its own Bag of `Event`s. The problem with this is that each `<bag>` element contains a `<key>` element. That key points to the `Parent` property of `Event`. It also makes the `Parent` column in the `Event`s table a foreign key to the table which contains the Bag! But one column can't be a foreign key to several tables and I'm getting an exception on insert.

I've also tried to make the `Parent` field in the `Event`s table a many-to-any kind of field. That worked. But when I want to make the relation bidirectional, meaning, to add the bags to the descendants of `Element` I come back to the same problem. Bag => foreign key => exception on insert.

I'm sure this case isn't as unique as it seems. 
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late, but I have some advise.

If you are using "table per concrete class", it is as if you would map completely independent tables. So you need separate foreign keys or many-to-any.

many-to-any stores the type name and NH knows to where the foreign key points. But it's impossible to have constraints on such a foreign key.

If you have several bags having items of the same type, make sure they all define different foreign keys:

```
<class name="A">
  <!-- ... -->
  <bag name="Events">
    <key column="A_FK"/>
    <one-to-many class="Event"/>
   </bag>
</class>

<class name="B">
  <!-- ... -->
  <bag name="Events">
    <key column="B_FK"/>
    <one-to-many class="Event"/>
   </bag>
</class>
```

You can have foreign key constraints on such a foreign key, but no not-null constraint, because only one of these foreign keys is used.

To really have only one foreign key with all the constraints, you need to map the element to a separate table.